# Why is CamCard's REST API returning HTTP 406 Not Acceptable when using HttpClient in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

When trying to use CamCard's REST API to scan a business card for information using .NET 4.5+'s HttpClient in C#, the server consistently returns HTTP 406 - Not Acceptable. The inner error number is '-2 - Invalid HTTP body', which is not much help.

The HttpClient is set up to accept application/json, and includes the JPG of the card to scan as multipart/form-data content.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours digging away at this in the debugger and in Fiddler so that you don't have to.

It turns out that the Content-Type header (multipart/form-data) declares its boundary value with a GUID, which it puts in quotes.

The JPG you attach is surrounded by this GUID (no quotes).

This is IETF-allowed; however, the CamCard server does not strip the quotes and instead searches for that literal boundary-in-quotes to find the start and end of the file, which of course it fails on.

So you have to set your own custom, quote-less boundary.

The INTSIG/CamCard lads might fix up their server sometime; even if they do, this code approach will still work.

I'll cut to the chase and provide a code snippet (no error handling):

```
async Task<string> DoCamCardAsync()
    {
        var cli = new HttpClient();
        cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Why use a custom boundary for multipart/form-data?
        // .NET sticks the thing in quotes in the header; the CamCard server goes nuts for the quotes (takes them literally); while the
        // actual boundary is delineated in the request by the unquoted boundary.
        var boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
        {
            form.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            form.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            byte[] cardBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file path here, or use stream instead");
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(cardBytes);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name="\"upfile\"",
                FileName = "\"card_m.jpg\""
            };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
            form.Add(fileContent);

            var sURl = "https://bcr1.intsig.net/BCRService/BCR_VCF2?user=[your username here]&pass=[your key here]&json=1&lang=1";
            var response = await cli.PostAsync(sURl, form);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Update from INTSIG: The older WebClient has no such issues:

            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                jsonBytes = wc.UploadData(
                    String.Format("http://bcr1.intsig.net/BCRService/BCR_VCF2?user={0}&pass={1}&lang={2}&json=1", user, pass, lang),
                    jpgFileAsByteArray);
            }
            // convert return data to string
            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonBytes);